App not starting with cryptic Passenger log error
I have a Rails app set up with Passenger + Nginx.
When trying to access the app I get the following error in passenger's logs:
/home/my_user/.rbenv/versions/3.3.1/bin/ruby: No such file or directory -- Passenger AppPreloader: /home/my_user/domains/my_domain/app/current (LoadError)

However the file /home/my_user/.rbenv/versions/3.3.1/bin/ruby and the directory /home/my_user/domains/my_domain/app/current both exist...
I have tried many things but I'm not even sure how to investigate the issue... any suggestions?

Disabling Passenger's "smart spawning" made the issue go away, but I'm still not sure why... https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/indepth/ruby/spawn_methods/#i-m-running-into-a-problem-is-it-caused-by-smart-spawning

I have same issue, and your fix worked for me. But I don't know why either....

This is an issue with the Passenger Docker.
Issue has been raised for the bug: https://github.com/phusion/passenger-docker/issues/409
As a quick fix which worked for me, you can add below line in your Dockerfile:
RUN gem install bundler --force -N -v "$(tail -n 1 Gemfile.lock | tr -d '[:blank:]\n')" && bundle --version


Seems like an issue with bundler, not Docker, but good find. Thanks

After upgrading Alma Linux kernel to 4.18.0-553.8.1.el8_10.x86_64 and deploying an updated Rails 7.1 app, passenger started to return the same No Such File or Directory error.  Disabling passenger's smart spawning error made the problem go away.
Using passenger 6.0.23

You need to make sure the version inside Gemfile.lock's BUNDLED WITH below matches the bundle version existing at server.
So:

Go to server, run: bundle -v (Make sure you are running the correct ruby version as well)
Take step 1 output and write it at your Gemfile.lock file below at BUNDLED WITH:

at:
RUBY VERSION
   ruby 3.1.6p260

BUNDLED WITH
   2.5.13

Credit: Here

bundle update --bundler is how to update that version number.
